# Set the default page layout of a PDF file with DomPDF

Tags: php, dompdf

I am using DomPDF to generate PDF-Files. This works fine, but I want to set the default page layout which is used by opening the document. I want to have a 100% view when the document is viewed. Actually the page is streched to the max width of the window. 
Does anybody know a solution how to set the page layout to "single site"?

Regards,
Lothron

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in dompdf by specifying the view in a meta element, e.g.

```
<meta name="dompdf.view" content="FitV" />
```

or

```
<meta name="dompdf.view" content="XYZ,0,0,1" />
```

You can also call the `set_default_view()` method of the canvas class, e.g.

```
$dompdf->get_canvas()->set_default_view('FitV')
```

Using the above method can only be done after the PDF document has been instantiated. As of dompdf 0.6.1 that is done after calling `$dompdf->render()`.

Ref: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/dompdf/7L2xMLwmH-Y/Et2mBNny51QJ